# linker error with openssl (trying SH1 example)

Tags: c++, openssl, c++builder, sha

I'm trying to compile an example of how to implement SHA1 but I keep getting this error:

```
[Linker Error] Unresolved external '_SHA1' referenced from C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\BORLAND\CBUILDER6\PROJECTS\UNIT1.OBJ
```

I downloaded openssl files from their website, I tried both copying the headers directory to my project directory and copying it to my includes directory, but nothing.

here's the example code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i;
    unsigned char ibuf[] = "compute sha1";
    unsigned char obuf[20];

    SHA1(ibuf, strlen(ibuf), obuf);

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%02x ", obuf[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}x
```

P.S: I'm using Borland C++ Builder 6

Comment: This is a link error. You're project isn't setup to link with the OpenSSL libcrypto library. It would seem you stopped halfway through the instructions on using libcrypto in your Windows program. Thankfully (for me) I use Visual Studio, so I have no idea in BC-builder where to add lib paths and linker instructions. But dig deep enough in your docs and you will find it.

Comment: Borland C++ Builder 6 (circa 2002) is ancient by most standards. Why are you using it, if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: @noloader I'm using it because my instructor gave it to me.

Comment: @noloader: I use C++Builder 6 in my day job, because my employer requires me to.  OpenSSL works just fine in it.  You should not criticize people's choice of dev tools.

Comment: Remy - it was not a criticism. I was just curious why the tools was being used. Its no different than the curiosity of someone saying, "I'm using Fedora 1 (circa 2003) for my webserver platform". Also, there may be compatibility problems between Shining Light's Win32OpenSSL and C++ Builder due to different runtimes.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the OpenSSL .lib files to your project via "Add to project..." or use `#pragma comment`

```
#pragma comment(lib, "ssl_lib_file_here.lib")

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
```

Comment: yeah, except that there're no files with extension '.lib' in the directory the setup I downloaded installed. there's a folder 'include' full with headers. I tried to add those header to my project but no results..

Comment: Then what did you download from OpenSSL site? A source tarball? Did you try [binaries](http://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html)?

Comment: @Ddmity a setup (.exe) file

Comment: I used [this installer](http://slproweb.com/download/Win32OpenSSL-1_0_1f.exe). It installs OpenSSL/include and OpenSSL/lib directories.

Comment: @Ddimty same problem, I downloaded the installer from the link you posted, I added the paths to C++ Builder but still the same error.

Comment: @Ddimtry by the way, when I first run the installer it says something about "Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable " not installed on my PC, is it necessary ?

Comment: Try to copy all `OpenSSL\lib\*.lib` files to the Builder6 lib directory. The Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable is required by OpenSSL DLLs and command line tools.

Comment: Also you can use `implib` to get `libeay32.lib`, `libssl32.lib`, `ssleay32.lib` from appropriate DLLs and add them to the project.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov: copying the shipped .lib files will not work as they are meant for VC++ and not compatible with BCB.  Calling `IMPLIB` on the DLLs is the correct solution.

Comment: @DmitrySokolov seems like libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib were enough

Comment: @RemyLebeau I was googling how to use implib but while looking I found  .lib files allready converted if this is what this process is called.

Comment: @MoheTheDreamy: `IMPLIB` (IMPort LIBrary) does not *convert* existing .lib files. It reads the source DLL files directly and then *creates* new .lib files that are compatible with the compiler that `IMPLIB` belongs to.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see, this makes more sense. 
but tell me, if I need to compile my program in another computer, do I have to install the whole library and include all the files or is it enough I copy the headers I used and those two .lib files and add them to my project ?

Comment: All you need is the headers and .lib files, and don't forget to deploy the DLLs with the compiled executable.

Answer (score 1):

> I downloaded openssl files from their website,

And

> ... except that there're no files with extension '.lib' in the directory the setup I downloaded installed

You need to use [Shining Light's Win32OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) or build OpenSSL yourself.

If you use Shining Light's version, everything is already built. While Thomas Hruska keeps Win32OpenSSL up to date with OpenSSL releases, I don't think he offers anything compatible with the version of C++ Builder 6 (circa 2002) you are using.

If you want to build OpenSSL from sources on the Win32 platform, then see `INSTALL.W32` and `INSTALL.W64` in the root directory of the OpenSSL distribution.

I believe you have a third option. That option is to grab a modern IDE. Microsoft offers a trial version of [Visual Studio](http://www.visualstudio.com/) (the link for the Trial is on the right of the page). Embarcadero also offers a free trial version of [C++ Builder XE5](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder). Both should work with Shining Light's Win32OpenSSL.

Comment: Shining Light's OpenSSL DLLs work just fine with C++Builder 6. I use them myself.  All you have to do is create an import .lib file for C++Builder using its command line `IMPLIB` tool and then add that file to your project.  The standard OpenSSL header files work fine as-is.